# ESP.deepSleep For Esp8266 for 22 hours

Tags: c, arduino-esp8266

I've got a really cool project where I have a camera trap in the wild monitoring cougars in the mountains. My camera trap is a wifi capable battery powered security camera. I have a wifi router built out of an ESP32 that I want to power up for two hours a day (mid day for best solar power). The camera is in some difficult terrain and it save a huge amount of time and energy to download the camera from a few hundred feet away.

Anyway.. question is:

I'm using a wemos D1 to control the relay. I want the wemos to wake up at 11am and turn on the router power. Then turn off the router power about two hours later. Doesn't have to be super accurate. Then go into deep sleep for 22 hours.

ESP.deepSleep(30e6); is working great for testing and will sleep for 30 seconds
ESP.deepSleep(60e6 * 60UL * 2UL); is working great for two hours

My question is do I need the UL on the end of the 60 and the 2?

ESP.deepSleep(60e6 * 60UL * 22UL); I'm about to test this for 22 hours of deep sleep but is there a better way to go about this? Thanks.

I've got the code working I'm just wondering if I'm doing it the best way over all.

Comment: Ok so after a little more testing the ESP.deepSleep(60e6 * 60UL * 22UL); is not actually working. I'm now trying ESP.deepSleep(36e8); to get one hour.

Comment: Writing `60UL` has type `unsigned long int`, whereas plain `60` has type `int`.  In this particular case it makes no difference which you write because when you multiply either of these types by `60e6`, which is a double, then they both get converted to double just the same.

Comment: I've removed your irrelevant tags esp8266 and sleep.  Knowing whether UL is required is just a question of the C language.

Comment: @TomV ESP8266 is not irrelevant, That circuit has a max sleep time (when <>0) of ~3.5h and (60e6 * 60 * 22) uS is 22 h ...

Comment: So the answer I've discovered is that I don't need deep sleep, the power consumption of the wemos d1 is so low that just using the VOID LOOP to set a relay on and off is working very well. Thanks every one, answer found.

Comment: Make a loop to call 11 times the deep sleep for 2 hours.